# Unity 3D build file fails to open in browser

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am using the latest version of unity 3d 5.3.1f1. I have built a web player file. I have tried both firefox and interntet explorer but cannot play the build file in the browser. I'm using windows 10 64 bit and my unity is also 64 bit. Thought installing 32 bit web player will do the work but it didn't.

[image]

Comment: What errors, if any, show up on the screen and in the browser's error console?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was created by idm extension. I just unchecked mozilla firefox from idm's browser system integration and it worked.